# How to add row to html table from inputs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I'm trying to to add a row to an HTML table from inputs using jQuery.

The idea is to get values from HTML inputs and then add them as a row in the table. When I click on the "add step" button the inputs are added but the table shows and then disappears!
How can I solve that ?

**HTML:**

```
<form class="col-md-offset-1">
     <div class="form-group">
         <select class="selectpicker" name="operation" id="operation">
             <option value="Add">Add</option>
             <option value="Minus">Minus</option>
             <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
             <option value="Divide">Divide</option>
         </select>

         <input type="number" name="value" id="value" />
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add_step">Add step</button>
     </div>

     <div class="">
         <table id="table_op"  bgcolor="#B0BEC5">
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_btn" name="submit" value="submit"  >Calculate</button>
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"  id="reset_btn" name="reset" value="reset"  >Reset</button>
     </div>
  </form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 1;
    $("#add_step").click(function(){

        $('#table_op').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
        $('table tr:last td:eq(0)').html(index+'. ');
        $('table tr:last td:eq(1)').html($("#operation").val());
        $('table tr:last td:eq(2)').html($("#value").val());
        index++;
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ?? What do you think `location.reload();` at the end of the function  does?

Comment: why do you have `location.reload()`?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, `location.reload()` shouldn't be in your code as it just reloads the page from scratch.

Next, you shouldn't have a `submit` button because you aren't submitting data anywhere, you are simply trying to do some calculations, so a regular `button` is what's needed. Additionally, with the `button` element, you don't need to supply a `value` attribute since the element isn't going to contain any data that needs to be submitted along with a form.

Additionally, `bgcolor` is no longer valid as an HTML attribute. All styling should be done in CSS.

Also, your HTML is not valid (you have an extra closing `div`).

Lastly, your code that adds the new row can be much simpler if you prepare the code first and append it last.

```js
var index = 1;
    
$("#add_step").click(function(){
  var op = $("#operation").val();
  var val = $("#value").val();
  $('#table_op').append('<tr><td>' + index + '. ' + '</td><td>' + op + '</td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
  index++;   
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
#table_op {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   background-color:#B0BEC5;
}

td {
  margin:3px;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="operation" id="operation">
      <option value="Add">Add</option>
      <option value="Minus">Minus</option>
      <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
      <option value="Divide">Divide</option>
    </select>
   
    <input type="number" name="value" id="value" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add_step">Add step</button>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    
    <table id="table_op"></table>
  </div>
  <hr>
    
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_btn" name="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"  id="reset_btn" name="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload()` function reloads the page.

You may remove the `reload()' function if you don't have data persistent.

[location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)